# Cannot use SoftwareSerial and RS485 protocol in the same code

Tags: arduino, rs485, c++

Could someone help me ?

I want to make 5 nanos communicating through RS485 protocol with my Arduino Uno master.
This part is working great by using the code of http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428

Now, I want my Uno to communicate those datas (from nanos) to an ESP32 through UART.

My problem is : when I do my Uno send data to my ESP32, the Uno can no anymore communicate avec Nanos through RS485 protocol.

Would you have an idea of my issue ?

My code:

````
#include "RS485_protocol.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#include <LedsHorloge.h>
//#include "FastLED.h"
#include "debug.h"



#define TOTAL_NUMBER_RC 5               

const byte ENABLE_PIN = 3;             
const byte LED_PIN_ERREUR = 10;           

byte RCnumberCalled = 1;                  

SoftwareSerial rs485 (5, 6);            



int etatEsclave[TOTAL_NUMBER_RC][2] ;    

int flagRedemarrageJeu = 0;             


void fWrite (const byte what)
  {
  rs485.write (what);  
  }


int fAvailable ()                       
  {
  return rs485.available ();  
  }

int fRead ()                           
  {
  return rs485.read ();  
  }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SET UP
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  rs485.begin (28800);               
  pinMode (ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode (LED_PIN_ERREUR, OUTPUT); 


  Serial.println("START");           



}  // FIN SET UP




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// LOOP
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void loop()
{


  byte msg [] = { RCnumberCalled,                 
                  flagRedemarrageJeu             
                };                                


  digitalWrite (ENABLE_PIN, HIGH);         

  sendMsg (fWrite, msg, sizeof msg);           


  // ---- When I add this snippet of code my Uno can no anymore communicate with my Nanos ---
  SoftwareSerial Ardu2Esp (8, 9);
  Ardu2Esp.begin(9600);
  Ardu2Esp.write(0x01);Ardu2Esp.flush();
  Serial.println("Donnees envoyees vers ESP");

  digitalWrite (ENABLE_PIN, LOW);                 



  byte buf [7];                                   numéro des cartes Arduino


  byte received =  recvMsg (fAvailable, fRead, buf, sizeof buf);


  digitalWrite (LED_PIN_ERREUR, received == 0);    // turn on LED if error    

  if ( received && buf[0]==RCnumberCalled )        
  {                                                

      Serial.println("Communication succeeded");

  }


  if (RCnumberCalled>TOTAL_NUMBER_RC)              
  {
    RCnumberCalled=1;                               
  }
} // FIN LOOP()

```
````

Comment: I don't think you should have the serial initialization in your loop. Try moving it out and see if that helps. I'm also not sure you can have multiple software serials at the same time?

Comment: Okay, you can have multiple software serial ports, but only one can receive data a time.

Comment: @hekete thank you, you are right, I have moved the Serial initialization outside from the loop and now it works !